# Elastic search highlighting sparse fields is slow

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, highlight, sparse-matrix

I recently started using elasticsearch. I have documents where there is a parent-child relationship, but i decided to instead store the children in numbered fields. For example:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "parent1",
    "child": {
        "1": {
            "id": "13"
            "content": "child 13 content"
        },
        "2": {
            "id": "25"
            "content": "child 25 content"
        },
        "3": {
            "id: "75"
            "content": "child 75 content"
        },
        "4": {
            "id": "125"
            "content": "child 125 content"
        }
    }
}
```

I did this so i can use highlight on these fields, and easily find out the ID of the highlighted child later. I use a highlighter like this:

```
"highlight": {
    "order": "score",
    "fields": {
        "name": {
            "number_of_fragments": 0
        },
        "child.*.content": {
        }
    }
}
```

This structure results in a lot of empty fields, one parent may have hundreds of children, while most of them only has a couple or none.

I ran some test searches and the highlighting was pretty slow. Then i tried to limit the highlighted fields to the maximum number of fields that was in my test search. (1 of the results contained 36 children, so instead of using "child.*.content" in my highlighter i replaced it with children 1-36). To my surprise, it reduced the search time by 10 times. The i tried adding fields 37-72 to the highlight, and it almost doubled search time.

Its a bit surprising to me that highlighting empty fields would take so much time. Is there any highlighting method that handles sparse fields better? Or any way to force the highlighter to skip those fields (or define how the highlighter handles empty fields)?

I really want to avoid using parent/child relationships, it would be so much easier to work with the current structure.